# Is there a difference between IOT and computer network

Tags: networking, iot

Is there difference between iot and computer network in framing , flow and error control , MAC , switching layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the network stack used for the IOT device, the answer is going to depend.

IOT devices use different network technology to connect. Some connect using power over line, some use wireless protocols like Zigbee, others connect using regular Wifi or Bluetooth. Others, like Wyze, use completely proprietary network technology and protocols.

In short, if you are comparing with an IOT device that has an Ethernet port or a Wifi adapter, They are going to share the same Layer 1 and 2 as a computer with an Ethernet or wireless adapter.

If you are comparing with a Wyze device, a LORA device, a Zigbee device, then the answer would be that the layer 1 and 2 would be different than the same computer